# Get specific element in a list or array using EL

Tags: arrays, list, jakarta-ee, el

Is it possible to get specific element in list or array using EL in a Java EE page (Facelets or JSP), or do I have to create a custom EL method?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the brace notation `[]` wherein you specify the (zero-based) index of the element you'd like to retrieve.

```html
<p>This is the 3rd item of the list: #{bean.list[2]}</p>
```

This syntax does basically the same as `bean.getList().get(2)`.

This is equivalent for arrays.

```html
<p>This is the 3rd item of the array: #{bean.array[2]}</p>
```

This syntax does basically the same as `bean.getArray()[2]`.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: Nice! I initially thought this was only applicable for Maps only. Thanks!

Comment: @Fritz: it's applicable on bean properties as well like `#{bean[propertyName]}`.