# How to access Set element in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf-2, el

i want to get specific element in a Set in JSF 2
please advise how to do that.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what do you want to do?

Comment: @SJuan76, i want to be able to do something like in the following post on a set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637285/how-to-get-specific-element-in-a-list-in-jsf-2

Comment: in that case you should create something like this `public List getSetAsList(){return new ArrayList(mySetVariable);}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is not specific to JSF/EL. Already in plain Java you **cannot** access a specific element in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). The `Set` has no method like `get(index)` as the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has. You need to convert the `Set<T>` to a `T[]` array or a `List<T>` so that you can access it by an index.

This works in a predictable way for [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) or [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) only as the elements are then inserted in respectively the sorted order or insertion order. This would not make any sense when it's a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) as you cannot reliably predict beforehand at which index the element would end up.

If you're using EL 2.2 (your question history confirms this), then you can just use [`Set#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) to convert it to an array and then use the brace notation `[]` to access the element by index. The below example prints the second item of the array representation of the `#{bean.someSet}`.

```html
#{bean.someSet.toArray()[1]}
```

Again, this makes no sense if it's an unordered set like `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is quite unclear, but **JSF2 doesn't really support Set**.

Components like `ui:repeat` or `h:datatable` always need a *sort* to display data, so your best choice will be to convert your `Set` to a `List` first.