# How can I get element from list in JSTL (not forEach)?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm in a `forEach` and would like to get an element (from `listName`) with proportional id as `forEach` loop element.

```
<% i=0; %>
<c:forEach var="account" items="${ctx.model.accounts}">
    <c:out value="${listName.get(${i})}" />
    <% i++; %>
</c:forEach>
```

Is this even possible?

I mean `${listName.get(${i})}` is of course wrong, but how can I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need scriptlets to achieve that.

```
<c:forEach var="account" items="${ctx.model.accounts}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <c:out value="${listName[loopStatus.index]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

But the fact that you have two parallel lists is, IMHO, a smell. Why don't you have a single list, where each element would allow access to the account and to the corresponding element in listname?

Comment: cause there I need to create new model class with super(); and add just a single property...

Comment: but yeah, your solution is correct so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`${listName[i]}` will give you the element from `listName`.

Check [Get specific element in a list or array using EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637285/get-specific-element-in-a-list-or-array-using-el) for details.

Comment: Got warning: `cannot resolve property or method 'i' (dynamic property?)`

Comment: Better use `varStatus` as suggested by JB.